# Is Linq and foreach in one statement preferable to 2 separate explicit statements?

Tags: c#, linq

I just saw a code like this

```
foreach (var item in Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty))
```

I am used to coding like this:

```
var items = Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty).AsEnumerable<Whatever>();
foreach (var item in items)
```

which one is preferable and why?

Comment: Well in your first version you're not calling `AsEnumerable()`. In your second version you are... so they're not the same in that respect. But other than that, they're equivalent... use whatever is most readable in the context.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am used to calling AsEnumerable, maybe I don't need to.

Comment: No, you generally don't need to call `AsEnumerable()` - not if you're just going to iterate over the result.

Comment: Noone noticed the OP wrote `var items = item in Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty).AsEnumerable<Whatever>();` which is just wrong and won't compile? :-)

Comment: @Jcl : is it suppose to be (item in Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty)).AsEnumerable<Whatever>(); ?

Comment: @Arjang it's even worse :-D `in` operator is a part of the `foreach` statement

Comment: @Arjang nope, it's supposed to be: `var items = Items.Where(..)`, not `var items = item in Items.Where(...)`. You can't write the `in` in an assignment, that's part of the `foreach` statement

Comment: (btw, I knew it was a simple copy/paste typo, but I was curious why noone seemed to have noticed... ahh, brains ;-) )

Comment: @Jcl : Thanks, I usually use the other linq syntax, tried this in notepad. Maybe becuase they implicitly trusted the OP that he has at least bothered testing it, it is a shortcoming on my part. Also I distracted them by asking preference between two things that both are suppose to work. I can only code with ide and not with my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query is simple like in your case, it is fine to use the first approach. (We're comparing Readability here)

Also, in your case, items will not be Enumerated and `items`  will not hold data until the first iteration of the loop. This is called **Deferred Execution**.

Why are you using `AsEnumerable<Whatever>()` ? It seems meaningless.

```
var items = Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty).ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
}
```

is different from this :

```
var items = Items.Where(s => s.SomeBoolProperty);
foreach (var item in items)
{
}
```

The second uses **Deferred Execution**, the first Enumerates the results using `ToList()`. So if you Debug, you can actually see the results before the `foreach`. However in the second approach, you'll need to click (Enumerate) or step into the `foreach` in order to see the results.

Comment: @Jcl Sorry, i was in a rush. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The cast to `IEnumerable` is not needed. Since the `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, where is also the type of the object on which you apply the `Where`.

> which one is preferable and why?

It is a matter of opinion. I would prefer the second option since it's more clear to me. Technically speaking both versions are equivalent. There isn't any difference.The reason why it is more clear to me is that the code is more readable.

Initially you define a filtering and later you just iterate through the items that pass this filter.

Comment: I would also use the second approach without the cast

Comment: I would use the first approach. In the second I will wonder where he will use items again